# Legacy Site vulnerable to XSS Attack

Tags: xss

I'm experiencing XSS in a legacy site.

The Parameter vulnerable to this attack is: `ldapSearch.jsp?f=`

After adding the XSS payload to check whether it is vulnerable or not: `"><img src=x onerror=prompt(0);>`

The URL will look like:

http://idenservices.hostname.com/axrac/ldapSearch.jsp?f=%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=x%20onerror=prompt%280%29;%3E

The XSS pop up comes up and proves that the site is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Snippet from JSP

```
<tr>
    <td class="required">*</td>
    <td class="label"><h3>Enter User's Core ID</h3></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="userid" size="25" maxlength="20"  onkeypress="return isAlphaNumberKey(event)"  onblur="return LowerCaseAlphanumeric(document.getElementById('userid'));"><a href="javascript: userlookup('userid','frmEditUser');" class="link">Lookup User</a></td>
</tr>
```

Snippet from JS

```
function userlookup(fieldName, formName) 
{
    var uri = "/axrac/ldapSearch.jsp?f=" + formName + "&f1=" + fieldName;
    msgWindow=open(uri,'lookup','width=600,height=400,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
    msgWindow.focus();
}
```

Adding ldapsearch.jsp

```
<%
    String backFieldName  = request.getParameter("f1");
    String backFormName   = request.getParameter("f");
%>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="PageSubHeader1">
<tr class="bg">
    <td class="flag">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="banner" width="100%"><h2>LDAP Search</h2></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="PageIntroduction">
<tr>
    <td class="copy">
    <br/>When searching for a person by their name, please provide 2 or more letters for their first and last name.
    If less than 2 letters are entered for both fields or if one field is empty, the search may not return any results.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class="HorizontalRule"></p>

<form action='ldapSearchResults.jsp' method='post'>
<input type="HIDDEN" name="backFieldName"   value="<%=backFieldName%>">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="backFormName"    value="<%=backFormName%>">


<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="Forms">
<tr>
    <td class="required">*</td>
    <td class="instruction" colspan="2"><h2>Indicates required field</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="required">*</td>
    <td class="label"><h3>First Name</h3></td>
    <td class="field"><input type=text name='firstName' size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="required">*</td>
    <td class="label"><h3>Last Name</h3></td>
    <td class="field"><input type=text name='lastName' size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="label" colspan="2"><h3>- Or -</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="required">*</td>
    <td class="label"><h3>Core ID</h3></td>
    <td class="field"><input type=text name='coreID' size="20"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p class="HorizontalRule"></p>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="Buttons">
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" class="systemButton1" value="Submit Form" id="Submit"> <input type="reset" class="systemButton2" value="Reset Form" id="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not see any issue with JavaScript, but still it is prone to XSS attack.Need help in understanding why it is vulnerable and what should I do to fix this.

Comment: It sounds like your tool is complaining that `ldapSearch.jsp` is vulnerable. Since you haven't shown us any code that does anything with user input form that program, it isn't possible to explain why it is vulnerable.

Comment: @Quentin : Thanks for your reply!! Just edited the question with ldapSearch.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Need help in understanding why it is vulnerable

You take user input here:

```
String backFieldName  = request.getParameter("f1");
```

Then your output it, without modification, here:

```
<input type="HIDDEN" name="backFieldName"   value="<%=backFieldName%>">
```

(You do the same with other data too, but we'll use this for the example).

This allows anyone to craft a link that contains a `">` followed by any HTML (including `<script>` elements or a Payment Required form) they want, send it to someone, and then have their HTML appear on your site when that person follows the link.

> and what should I do to fix this.

Either convert any characters with special meaning in HTML to their respective entities, or run the data through a whitelist to filter out potentially bad input.

Further reading: [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)